# How to navigate out of my php localhost server project (wamp server)?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I am creating a php page and using a localhost server(wamp server).
When i try to navigate throw a link out of my project it give me 403 error

I need to know how to get red of the localhost direction from the link

```
http://localhost/my%20project/%EF%BB%BFhttp://www.damascusuniversity.edu.sy/
```

my code is

```
<?php
$link="http://www.damascusuniversity.edu.sy/";
 echo( "<a  href='");echo $link; echo("'>");
   echo $link;
   echo( "</a>");
?>
```

Comment: The link should probably have `http://` in front. Like `http://www.damascus.com`

Comment: Are you at the correct address when you get the 403 error?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, it was wrong to delete http://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in wamp installation as i think,
because when i uninstalled wamp 2.2 and installed wamp 3,and then uninstalled it and back to wamp2.2 it works fine as its expected, and the links worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate an external url, you must provide full url including http or https if destination host supports ssl. for example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">click here</a>
```

by default the path will be assumed relative and will be appended to your application's base url.

Comment: I am providing full URL but it didn't work becaue it give the local server directory automatically before the link i provide when i tested the link on my localhost server